# Check for week day string in different languages

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have class that output string that depend on current day. It work's fine in Russian, but, when i switch to another language its not work. This is how i write it:

```
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE"];

    // Current day

    NSString *currentDay = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

    // Mon

    if ([currentDay isEqualToString:@"понедельник"]){
        _mon.textColor = COLOR_BG;
    }
```

Is there any easy way to make that code work in other languages? Not depend on current iPhone selected language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing the string here which is different for another language.

So you either have a translation for Every weekday language or my recommended way is to change the formatter to return a integer of the week. If I not wrong is **e**

So it will be :

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"e"];
int current = [[dayDateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]] intValue];

if (currentDay == 1){
    _mon.textColor = COLOR_BG;
}
```

Comment: how do i make an int that represent week day number?

Comment: I updated it. Is off the TOP of my head, might have some error.